# UEC for grid or parallel computing?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-computing, ubuntu-enterprise-cloud

-Can I use the cloud to do "Grid computing"? what I need is parallel computing where I do some rendering and would like it to do some heavier calculations for matlab. To combined the computing power of some or all computers in to "one task" if it is running multiple threads

-How many controllers do i need before i start adding nods and what controllers?

-Any one have a cool ide of what to do with the 50 computers in a cloud like UEC or some thing else?

I have about 25 computers(cpu:Duo2.2ghz ram:2gb hdd:150gb) laying around from the "summer cleaning" and was thinking of making a cloud with UEC.

Comment: Check to make sure the models of those core 2 duo's support the VT-X extensions or else you'll go no where fast trying to get the Node Controllers to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you need is more like a traditional HPC cluster rather than a IaaS cloud computing platform. If you don't want to set up a HPC cluster from scratch there are cluster distros such as [ROCKS](http://www.rocksclusters.org) that make it easier, especially if you're a HPC newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Check MIT's StarCluster project.

This short 5 minute video will explain it:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC3lJcPq1FY&feature=player_embedded
```

It is built with AWS EC2, Boto and the Sun Grid Computing Engine (Guess that's Oracle Grid Computing Engine now).

From my view..  they've layered a "grid" computing architecture on top of EC2 and I think it most likely could work with Eucalyptus and UEC.

from MIT's site:

> > Installing StarCluster
> >
> > StarCluster is available via the Python Package Index (PyPI) and comes with two public >>Amazon EC2 AMIs (i386 and x86_64). Below are instructions for installing the latest >>stable release of StarCluster via PyPI (recommended). There are also instructions for >>installing the latest development version from github for advanced users.

Just watch this short 5 minute video by MIT which explains what StarCluster does on EC2 very well.

After looking at it I think it should be easy to install and use with either Eucalyptus or Ubuntu's UEC as both share compatibility with AWS EC2 via boto/Euca2ools.

It only took me about 5 minutes to install StarCluster using Python's easy_install.   Everything worked just as in the video.

There is a single master config file that is very easy to figure out and should be
able to make changes for Eucalyptus or UEC.

brian